# Trying to simplify expression with factorials

Tags: math

First off, apologies if there is a better way to format math equations, I could not find anything, but alas, the expressions are pretty short.

As part of an assigned problem I have to produce some code in C that will evaluate x^n/n! for an arbitrary x, and n = { 1-10 , 50, 100}

I can always brute force it with a large number library, but I am wondering if someone with better math skills then mine can suggest a better algorithm than something with a O(n!)...

I understand that I can split the numerator to x^(n/2)*x^(n/2) for even values of n, and x*x^(n-1/2)*x^(n-1/2) for odd values of n. And that I can further change that into a logarithm base x of n/2.

But I am stuck for multiple reasons:

1 - I do not think that computationally any of these changes actually make a lot of difference since they are not really helping me reduce the large number multiplications I have to perform, or their overall number.

2 - Even as I think of n! as 1*2*3*...*(n-1)*n, I still cannot rationalize a good way to simplify the overall equation.

3 - I have looked at Karatsuba's algorithm for multiplications, and although it is a possibility, it seems a bit complex for an intro to programming problem.

So I am wondering if you guys can think of any middle ground. I prefer explanations to straight answers if you have the time :)

Cheers,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: ehh, my bad. I should have seen mentioned this earlier. The overall goal of the solution is to approximate the value of e^x, by summation of x^n/n!. So using a function that requires e^x as a factor would not work...nice suggestion though.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is there a programming language that doesn't have a function to calculate `e^x`?

Comment: I am sure C can calculate e^x but it is a bit besides the point I suppose. I still need to use that formula as the basis for the algorithm...

Comment: You said the overall goal is to approximate `e^x`. Why approximate it if you can just calculate it directly?

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to compute all the terms of the summation (put them in an array), and then sum them up in reverse order (i.e., smallest to largest) -- that reduces rounding error a little bit.

Note that you can compute the `k`-th term from the preceding one by multiplying by `x/k` -- you do not need to ever compute `x^n` or `n!` directly (this is important).

Comment: Good point about doing the summation in reverse order. Adding the small terms first ensures you'll have as much precision as possible.